# Remove white square around a png image

Tags: iphone, background, png, imageview

I have a png image of a pin. I add it as a subview onto another imageview. But when I add it I see a white square around the pin itself. How can I remove that white background. I can see that white square when I view the file in Preview application.
P.S. The platform is Mac OS X Snow Leopard. I'm developing an app for iPhone.I downloaded a png image from internet.

Comment: What application are you using?  Is it a graphics app like Adobe Illustrator?  Does this have anything to do with programming?  If it's just graphics, there's a [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) stack exchange...

Comment: development language/platform? is it for web, standalone, android or do you want to edit the image file with an editor? Need to give us something to work with.

Comment: It sounds like you need to edit the picture with whatever tools you have in Mac OS. Gimp (http://www.gimp.org/macintosh/) is freeware and great. This is not a question for SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open that image with photoshop then select layers and then u will see two layer one for your pin other for backgroundlayer.right click then delete backgroundlayer then save again.ur problem solved.

do with Layer window pan in photoshop